# update 2nd table column based on 1st table

Tags: sql

I have two tables. One is `Employee` and other is `Department`.

Employee table has following columns:

```
Name | Salary | Department Id
```

Department table has

```
Department Id| Department Name | SumofSalary
```

I want to update SumofSalary department wise

Code I have tried

```
update Department set sumofsalary =
(
    select D.deptid, SUM(E.salary) from Department D inner join Employesalary E 
    on d.deptid=e.deptid group by D.deptid
)
```

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Following will give you sum of salaries department wise and update in department table.

```
UPDATE D SET D.SumOfSalary = T.Salary FROM Department D JOIN 
(
    SELECT SUM(Salary) Salary, [Department ID] DeptID FROM Employee Group By [Deptartment ID]
) T ON T.DeptID = D.[Department ID]
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh, there is nothing in there which will not work for most of the platforms with little or no modification. Any how i assumed MS Sql Server.

Comment: "_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL_".

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code a simple subquery  Which will update the sum salary department wise

```
    UPDATE  dept
    SET dept.sum =h.totalSum  FROM (select  a.deptid, SUM( a.Salary) AS 
    totalSum FROM emp a
    Group By a.deptid) h WHERE 
    dept.deptid=h.deptid
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.